# What characters do I need to escape when returning HTML in my JSON array?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

returning HTML in my json array, what things do I have to escape for?

Answer (score 0):

HTML can be passed in JSON if standard JSON escaping rules are applied. Any json library (worth its weight in bytes) will do this for you.

In PHP:

```
json_encode('<body class="foo">');
```

Returns

```
"<body class=\"foo\">"
```

More info on http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is, you don't need to.  JSON encoding will handling everything for you.

However, depending on your other needs, if you want to strip tags, or make < into &lt;, then you can do so to the HTML string first, or do it at the client using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape anything. The Json serializer will take care of it:

```
return Json(new { html = "<html><body><div class=\"foo\">Hello</div></body></html>" });
```